# WebStorm auto import from react-native-web instead of from react-native for Image

Tags: react-native, webstorm

[image]

I am new to RN development. I am not entirely sure what should be imported from where.

##### Could someone explain

1. How react-native-web/Image is different from react-native/Image?
2. How do I default the auto-import option from react-native-web to react-native (Is that's necessary)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have `react-native-web` in your project's dependencies - the IDE suggests you symbols from this module in code completion and adds imports for them.
As a workaround, please add `react-native-web/**/*` to the **Do not import from** list in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript - Imports**.

It's not quite clear why it doesn't suggest imports from `react-native`; what IDE version do you use? [WEB-35144](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35144) is fixed in 2021.1

Comment: I have the latest version and I can tell you it is not fixed. Your solution also does not work.